# Regex for search term plus key value pairs

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Found many kvp regex's, but am looking for one that will do both a search term plus kvp.  For example if the search string is:

```
John Hennesey POLICY_NUMBER="POL-1-2345-6-780" EXPIRATION_DATE="2017-01-01T00:00:00" business_name="Hennesey Hen Houses" PREMIUM="between 100 and 400"
```

Using the regex
`(?<term>.?)(((?<key>\w+)(?<operator>(=|:|))"\s*(?<value>.*?)\s*")){0,}`

I would like the regex to return:

term is "John Hennesey"

a bunch key value pairs - policy_number with the value "POL-1-2345-6-780", expiration_date is "2017-01-01T00:00:00", business_name is "Hennesey Hen Houses", and premium is "between 100 and 400".

I can split this into two regex match/searches if necessary, doesn't have to be 1.

UPDATE:
@ctwheels Stupid question time - the first example you gave has a match, but I am unable to get to the key matches in c#.  It also appears (from the results) that "term" is required.  What am I doing wrong?

```
string ctWheels1 = @"(?<term>^.*?(?=\s*\w+[=:]?""))|(((?<key>\w +)(?<operator>([=:]?))""\s*(?<value>[^""]*)\s*""))";

string input = "john hennesey BUSINESS_NAME=\"Hennesey Hen Houses*\" policy_year:\"2017\" MINIMUM_PREMIUM_flag:\"y\"";
Regex c1 = new Regex(ctWheels1);
bool ismatch = c1.IsMatch(input);      // returns true
var x = c1.Matches(input);
int dummy = x.Count;                    // returns 1
```

@ctwheels - Stupid me, I was doing it wrong.

```
        string pattern = @"(?<term>^.*?(?=\s*\w+[=:]?""))|(((?<key>\w+)(?<operator>([=:]?))""\s*(?<value>[^""]*)\s*""))";
        string input = @"John Hennesey POLICY_NUMBER=""POL-1-2345-6-780"" EXPIRATION_DATE=""2017-01-01T00:00:00"" business_name=""Hennesey Hen Houses"" PREMIUM=""between 100 and 400""";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
```

Comment: [`(?<term>^.*?(?=\s*\w+[=:]?"))|(((?<key>\w+)(?<operator>([=:]?))"\s*(?<value>[^"]*)\s*"))`](https://regex101.com/r/C2xGV6/3/)? Note I changed `.*?` to `[^"]*` (this allows for better performance). Also, you don't need `{0,}` at the end, it's not doing anything. Plus you can use `*` instead of `{0,}`

Comment: [Is it something like this you're after](https://regex101.com/r/MyPfEx/1)?

Comment: You can also use [`(?:(?<term>^.*?(?=\s*\w+[=:]?"))\s*|\G(?!\A)\s*)(((?<key>\w+)(?<operator>([=:]?))"\s*(?<value>[^"]*)\s*"))`](https://regex101.com/r/C2xGV6/4/)

Comment: @ctwheels It is much easier with C#, [`^\s*(?<term>\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?:\s+(?<key>\w+)="(?<value>[^"]*)")*\s*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*%28%3f%3cterm%3e%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5cw%2b%29*%29%28%3f%3a%5cs%2b%28%3f%3ckey%3e%5cw%2b%29%3d%22%28%3f%3cvalue%3e%5b%5e%22%5d*%29%22%29*%5cs*%24&i=John+Hennesey+POLICY_NUMBER%3d%22POL-1-2345-6-780%22+EXPIRATION_DATE%3d%222017-01-01T00%3a00%3a00%22+business_name%3d%22Hennesey+Hen+Houses%22+PREMIUM%3d%22between+100+and+400%22) will do.

Comment: John, are you sure you want to get the `KeyValuePair<string, string>` or a dictionary? Are the keys not unique?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Ultimately I am after a dictionary - the keys should be unique, but not guaranteed so I will add or update the values.

Comment: I see, and do you expect a single match per input? Or do you expect multiple matches?

Comment: @ctwheels - Your first example fits it perfectly.  Thank you. (I accidentally upvoted your comment twice, and cannot upvote it for real now.  Sorry!)

Comment: @JohnHennesey Did you address me or ctwheels? Whose regex do you want to be posted?

Comment: [Did it work for you?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47547789/3832970)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regex that will match and capture the term into Group "term" and all other key-values into 2 groups, "key" and "value", and you may retrieve all the captured substrings using the Group *CaptureCollection*:

```
var rx = @"(?<term>\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?:\s+(?<key>\w+)=""(?<value>[^""]*)"")+";
var s = "John Hennesey POLICY_NUMBER=\"POL-1-2345-6-780\" EXPIRATION_DATE=\"2017-01-01T00:00:00\" business_name=\"Hennesey Hen Houses\" PREMIUM=\"between 100 and 400\"  Mike Ramsey POLICY_NUMBER=\"POL-2-2346-8-080\" EXPIRATION_DATE=\"2017-02-08T01:04:50\" business_name=\"Mike Ramsey Igloos\" PREMIUM=\"between 200 and 500\"";
var ms = Regex.Matches(s, rx);
foreach (Match m in ms)
{
    var term = m.Groups["term"].Value;
    Dictionary<string, string> dct = m.Groups["key"].Captures // Get Group "term" capture collection
            .Cast<Capture>()
            .Select(x=>x.Value)           // Convert to a list of values
            .ToList()
            .Zip(                         // Zip with the Group "value" substrings to get a dictionary
                m.Groups["value"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x=>x.Value).ToList(), 
                (k, v) => new { k, v }
            )
            .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
    Console.WriteLine("---- NEXT MATCH ----\nTerm: {0}", term); // Demo output
    foreach (var kvp in dct) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("KVP: {0}:{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Output of the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/28oZaN):

```
---- NEXT MATCH ----
Term: John Hennesey
KVP: POLICY_NUMBER:POL-1-2345-6-780
KVP: EXPIRATION_DATE:2017-01-01T00:00:00
KVP: business_name:Hennesey Hen Houses
KVP: PREMIUM:between 100 and 400
---- NEXT MATCH ----
Term: Mike Ramsey
KVP: POLICY_NUMBER:POL-2-2346-8-080
KVP: EXPIRATION_DATE:2017-02-08T01:04:50
KVP: business_name:Mike Ramsey Igloos
KVP: PREMIUM:between 200 and 500
```

The regex is

```
(?<term>\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?:\s+(?<key>\w+)="(?<value>[^"]*)")+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Cterm%3E%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B%29*%29%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Ckey%3E%5Cw%2B%29%3D%22%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5B%5E%22%5D*%29%22%29%2B&i=John%20Hennesey%20POLICY_NUMBER%3D%22POL-1-2345-6-780%22%20EXPIRATION_DATE%3D%222017-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%22%20business_name%3D%22Hennesey%20Hen%20Houses%22%20PREMIUM%3D%22between%20100%20and%20400%22%20Mike%20Ramsey%20POLICY_NUMBER%3D%22POL-2-2346-8-080%22%20EXPIRATION_DATE%3D%222017-02-08T01%3A04%3A50%22%20business_name%3D%22Mike%20Ramsey%20Igloos%22%20PREMIUM%3D%22between%20200%20and%20500%22).

**Details**

- `(?<term>\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)`
- `(?:\s+(?<key>\w+)="(?<value>[^"]*)")+` - 1 or more consecutive occurrences of

  - `\s+` -  1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?<key>\w+)` - Group *key*: 1 or more word chars
  - `="` - a literal substring
  - `(?<value>[^"]*)` - Group *value*: 0+ chars other than `"`
  - `"` - a `"`.

If the values can be just non-whitespace substrings (without double quotes), you may further enhance the pattern with

```
(?<term>\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?:\s+(?<key>\w+)=(?:"(?<value>[^"]*)"|(?<value>\S+)))+
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Cterm%3E%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B%29*%29%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Ckey%3E%5Cw%2B%29%3D%28%3F%3A%22%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5B%5E%22%5D*%29%22%7C%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5CS%2B%29%29%29%2B&i=John%20Hennesey%20POLICY_NUMBER%3D%22POL-1-2345-6-780%22%20EXPIRATION_DATE%3D%222017-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%22%20business_name%3D%22Hennesey%20Hen%20Houses%22%20PREMIUM%3D%22between%20100%20and%20400%22%20Mike%20Ramsey%20POLICY_NUMBER%3DPOL-2-2346-8-080%20EXPIRATION_DATE%3D%222017-02-08T01%3A04%3A50%22%20business_name%3D%22Mike%20Ramsey%20Igloos%22%20PREMIUM%3D%22between%20200%20and%20500%22).

If the term may have any chars but `=` in it, you may replace the *term* group pattern with `(?<term>[^=]*)` (see [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Cterm%3E%5B%5E%3D%5D*%29%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Ckey%3E%5Cw%2B%29%3D%28%3F%3A%22%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5B%5E%22%5D*%29%22%7C%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5CS%2B%29%29%29%2B&i=John%20%26*Hennesey--%2B%20POLICY_NUMBER%3D%22POL-1-2345-6-780%22%20EXPIRATION_DATE%3D%222017-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%22%20business_name%3D%22Hennesey%20Hen%20Houses%22%20PREMIUM%3D%22between%20100%20and%20400%22%20Mike%20Ramsey%20POLICY_NUMBER%3DPOL-2-2346-8-080%20EXPIRATION_DATE%3D%222017-02-08T01%3A04%3A50%22%20business_name%3D%22Mike%20Ramsey%20Igloos%22%20PREMIUM%3D%22between%20200%20and%20500%22)). If keys can contain more chars than word chars, but cannot contain whitespace, replace `(?<key>\w+)` with `(?<key>[^\s=]+)` (see [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Cterm%3E%5B%5E%3D%5D*%29%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Ckey%3E%5B%5E%5Cs%3D%5D%2B%29%3D%28%3F%3A%22%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5B%5E%22%5D*%29%22%7C%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5CS%2B%29%29%29%2B&i=John%20%26*Hennesey--%2B%20POLICY-12%2B%3A%3A_NUMBER%3D%22POL-1-2345-6-780%22%20EXPIRATION_DATE%3D%222017-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%22%20business_name%3D%22Hennesey%20Hen%20Houses%22%20PREMIUM%3D%22between%20100%20and%20400%22%20Mike%20Ramsey%20POLICY_NUMBER%3DPOL-2-2346-8-080%20EXPIRATION_DATE%3D%222017-02-08T01%3A04%3A50%22%20business_name%3D%22Mike%20Ramsey%20Igloos%22%20PREMIUM%3D%22between%20200%20and%20500%22)).